# Code completes error free but print function not working

Tags: python, printing, beautifulsoup, pickle

I am trying to learn python and i have been following a tutorial on youtube. So far been going good but got to a point where if i run the code it completes without error however it does not print what i want. I am copied down exactly what was in the tutorial and cannot find the difference. Just confused as to why it can complete the code but not print(tickers). Any help would be great, i have a feeling it is probably an easy fix that i am overlooking.

Cheers,

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests

def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table',{'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findALL('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findALL('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open("sp500tickers.pickle","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)

    print(tickers)

    return tickers

    save_sp500_tickers()
```

Comment: If your array will be empty then `print()` will print nothing (so make sure it isn't). And also your function `save_sp500_tickets()` call is inside itself.

Comment: `save_sp50_tickers()` presumably should not be inside the function definition: it should be de-indented

Answer (score 0):

the save_sp500_tickers() call is wrongly indented, so it is part of the function definition and will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. Removing the indent of save_sp500_tickers() worked.
Also i had to get rid of

```
for row in table.findALL('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findALL('td')[0].text
```

and turn it into

```
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.find_all('td')[0].text
```

turns out BeautifulSoup changed it in in more recent versions.